# ag-grid with angular typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ag-grid

I am trying to use Angular Typeahead (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with ag-grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/). I have set angularCompileRows to true and I have set up a cell editor for the typeahead, and the typeahead dropdown is being activated. However, the drop down list is hidden behind the other rows in the grid. How can I make sure that I can see the typeahead drop down over top of the other grid rows? I tried setting z-index to 9999 on the `<ul>` element using firebug, but the list was still hidden.

This is my Cell editor:

```
 // function to act as a class
    function TypeAheadCellEditor () {}

    // gets called once before the renderer is used
    TypeAheadCellEditor.prototype.init = function(params) {
        // create the cell

        this.eInput = document.createElement('input');
        this.eInput.setAttribute("typeahead", "cardCode for cardCode in getCardCodes($viewValue)");
        this.eInput.setAttribute("typeahead-loading", "loadCardCodes");
        this.eInput.setAttribute("typeahead-wait-ms", "300");
        this.eInput.setAttribute("ng-model", "selectedItemCode");
        this.eInput.value = params.value;

    };

    // gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
    TypeAheadCellEditor.prototype.getGui = function() {
        return this.eInput;
    };

    // focus and select can be done after the gui is attached
    TypeAheadCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
        this.eInput.focus();

    };

    // returns the new value after editing
    TypeAheadCellEditor.prototype.getValue = function() {
        return this.eInput.value;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your css:**

```
.ag-cell {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following options from [uib-typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead)

1. typeahead-append-to $ (Default: null) - Should the typeahead popup be appended to an element instead of the parent element?
2. typeahead-append-to-body $  (Default: false) - Should the typeahead popup be appended to $body instead of the parent element?